# CodeIgniter: How to set the default page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a multilingual website with CodeIgniter and now I would like to change the default url **www.myebsite.com** into **www.mywebsite.com/en/home**.

How can I change it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Setting Homepage ( Default Controller )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175934/codeigniter-setting-homepage-default-controller)

Comment: Ha you check into the config.php file?

Comment: Where exactly into the config.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the default controller to redirect to /en/home :

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        redirect('en/home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mariek, If I use redirect('en/home') in the default controller the page wil be redirected to www.mywebsite.com/en/home/en/home and not to www.mywebsite.com/en/home

Comment: it depends on your config. If the default route is "welcome/index", it will work, assuming "en/home" is not redirecting to "welcome/index". If the default route is already "en/home", you don't need to use a default controller.

Answer (score 14):

Navigate to `application/config/routes.php`

Find `$route['default_controller']`

And Replace to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'my-controller/my-method';
```

Comment: The controller's name is home...which method are you referring to?

Comment: If you followed codeigniter guidelines for the multilanguage then all you need to do is in the config file edit $config['language'] = 'english';

Comment: Hi, the $config['language'] has been already edited as per your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'my-controller/my-method';
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.