# 404 error while removing index.php in codeigniter

Tags: base-url, .htaccess

Some 1 please help me... 
I'm very new to PHP codeigniter.

I changed as per user guide in codeigniter. 
Now I'm getting 404 Page not found.
How to solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you removed index.php file. The first function working there is from the controller file which might be a welcome note. You can create a new index function by removing the existing index function & do what ever you are required. Also can set a new controller by default & do rest in the new file. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18175934/4229270

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/controllers.html

Comment: No issue... Thank u... I figured it out...