# codeigniter redirect from baseurl

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project with the my baseurl as `localhost/app`

my controller is blog so when I visit `localhost/app/blog` I get the information on the view. Although when I visit just `localhost/app` nothing shows just the header and the footer.

So my question is how do I either redirect to my main page which is `localhost/app/blog` when some enters in `localhost/app`

Or are there any other work arounds to fix this where it redirects to a controller when just the base url is called?

**My blog contoller** (I used index to see if it would automatically redirect.

```
  public function index(){

  $data['title'] = 'Newest';


  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Setting Homepage ( Default Controller )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175934/codeigniter-setting-homepage-default-controller)

Comment: In routes.php make blog as default controller